# How to control what WCF Authentication will deny?

Tags: wcf, authentication

I am learning and designing a WCF service. I have picked to use Windows credential as the authentication method, and I have configured it correctly, hopefully, because I can see the authentication audit log from event log viewer when I am testing my service hosted in the local machine.

But now I come up with this weird question: what users will not be authenticated under such configuration? Does my service authenticate all Windows user within the same Windows domain, or can I specify what specific users within my domain will/will not get authenticated?

Or, does it mean that I can only control what users (in my domain) can perform what operations my service is providing through authorization(that I know how to do)?

It sounds simple but all the material I found only tell you how to perform authentication, doesn't say how to deny authentication request.

Update:
After reading @syneptody answer, I still have two questions:

1. I must say my confusion between authentication and authorization is still there. The authentication means to identify the user. But if I want to tell a user belonging to the same domain as the service host(it's IIS, by the way), who just makes a request to my service, "you are not authenticated", what I really should say is "I do authenticate you, but you are not authorized (to perform your request)", is it right? There is not a state of "Unauthenticated" for a user in my domain? And what if a user not belonging to my domain makes a request? My service will tell him "You are not authenticated" or "You are not authorized"? As long as this user has an identity, the service will authenticate it, and continue to investigate whether it should be authorized?
2. @syneptody mentioned This "authorization" element. It belongs to ASP.NET, and it specifies which roles can/can't access the resource (whether it is the website or an application hosted in the website, depending on which Web.config file it is in). Is it right? But what if I don't use ASP.NET or don't host the WCF in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode, will it still work like that? Actually the requirement for us is to only provide the service, so I didn't think of using ASP.NET because in my opinion it is more like a web client consuming my service. 
   By the way, my usage scenario is this service will be hosted and consumed within intranet. So I choose Windows credential for authentication and Windows Groups for role-based authorization because it requires minimum work in my opinion.

Comment: To address question 1, remember AD is authenticating the user and IIS is authorizing the request.  In a Windows domain world authentication is always done by the domain controller.  So a 401 would be like you are not authenticated e.g. anonymous and this resource requires an authenticated user.  A 403 would be you are authenticated but not authorized.

Comment: To address question 2, the proposed solution does in fact require ASP.NET compatibility mode.  I am not condoning that one way or another... I am simply offering it as an approach since it is by far the easiest to implement.  Security in WCF is a very large and complex subject and there are several ways to do things.  If your solution can live in compatibility mode (and its been my experience that most enterprise services can) then this approach may work for you.

Comment: @syneptody thanks for your explanation, which helped me a lot. I have marked your post as answer. But maybe one last question: under my configuration (using Windows credential for authentication and Windows Groups for authorization, also disabling anonymous authentication), is there a chance for the situation "not authenticated" to happen? (With a request having whatever valid Windows credential, in the same domain, other domain, local machine ...)

Comment: An unauthenticated request is always possible.  However in this configuration IIS will throw a 401 before the request ever reaches your service.  This is because you have told IIS to disallow anonymous requests.  You can turn on failed request tracking in IIS to see this play out.  The key thing to remember is that there can be cases where you (as the service implementer) will not be able to respond to a specific event because IIS will deal with it before you get it.

Comment: @syneptody I didn't mean how it will react to anonymous request(I know IIS will turn it down with my setting). But what about a request with a valid Windows credential, but this credential is 1)in different Windows domain, or 2)without any domain but a local Windows machine? For the first case (in different domain), as long as it is accepted by AD (I think an AD can control more than one Windows domains), the authentication is passed through and the request will go to IIS for authorization, is this the correct path? And in the second case (without any domain), authentication will fail by AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

It does a pretty good job explaining the connection between WCF and ASP.NET.  If you are able to run your services in ASP.NET compatibility mode you can use the ASP.NET authorization rules.  In a domain environment where you can leverage Integrated Authentication there is no easier way to provide authorization to your services.

Your service implementation:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior]
public class Foo { ... }
```

Then in your configuration:

```
<system.web>   
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
      <allow roles="DOMAIN_SECURITY_GROUP" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>

    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still have two questions after the reading. 1. This <authorization> element belongs to ASP.NET, so in order to use it, I must have

Comment: Your question got truncated.  If you repost I will try to answer.

Comment: Yeah. I always found the space in the comment not enough for my further questions, after I started the comment. So please see my update in my original question post